# Proof $T(u-v)=T(u)-T(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if $T:V\to W$ is linear transformation, then $T(u-v)=T(u)-T(v)$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in $V$.

It has occurred to me to use induction with the example of a function like $y=2x$ and $y=e^x$ as map $T_1:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $T_2:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

But I would like a **more general abstract proof**. Could anyone provide it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should just use the three defining properties of a linear transformation. There will be two steps. You have to use one property to justify each step.

Comment: By definition: $$ 
T(u-v) = T(u+(-v)) = T(u) + T(-v) =  T(u) + T((-1)v) =  T(u) - T(v)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}T(u)&=T(u+0)\\&=T(u+(v+-v))\\&=T((u+-v)+v)\\&=T\bigl((u-v)+v\bigr)\\&=T(u-v)+T(v)\Longrightarrow T(u-v)=T(u)-T(v)\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to note that $u - v = u + (-1)v$ and then use the linearity of $T$.